# Getting the "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 is not registered..." error when running from Integration Services Catalog on server

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS project in SSDT for Visual Studio 2017.  It has to connect to several Excel workbooks as data sources.  The packages all run fine and connect with no errors when I run them in SSDT.  When I deploy them to the Integration Services Catalog of the SQL Server instance on that same server, I get the "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 is not registered..." error message.  I verified that this driver is installed on that server and it is the same server that the packages are on and running from in SSDT.  What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: I've set the flag in SSIS to T and F.  It still runs fine in the package but won't run from the server.  Any idea how to fix that?
Also, it's not running in a job just right-clicking and executing the master package from the Integration Services Catalog.  I know in the SQL Server Agent, you can set it to run in 32-bit mode.  But it's not in a job.

Comment: By T and F, I mean I am flipping the property flag in the SSIS project property page to True and False.  It gives the same error with either setting.  I have no idea what other setting there is in the Integration Services Catalog for this.